# How to get the SelectedItem from a ComboBox when using a Proxy?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I'm building a DataGrid with Entity Framework and MVVM Light pattern and thus I bind the Datagrid to a ListCollectionView like so:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding RequestsModelView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRequest, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

ViewModel:

```
public ListCollectionView RequestsModelView { get; set; }
        public Requests RequestsModel
        {
            get => RequestsModelView?.CurrentItem as Requests;
            set
            {
                RequestsModelView?.MoveCurrentTo(value);
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private void InitializeRequestsView()
        {
            RequestsModelView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(RequestsCollection) as ListCollectionView;

            RequestsModelView.CurrentChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => RequestsModel);
            };
        }
```

This works perfect when I use properties from this Requests-ListColletionView (i.e. values from Requests-table Entity).
Now I want to add a DataGrid ComboBox that gets its values from another table (i.e. Requests_Functions-table Entity). I managed to get it working with a proxy (taken from https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/). Here is the XAML-code:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn  
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Requests_Functions.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data.FunctionNamesCollection, Source={StaticResource proxy}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                            SelectedItem="{Binding Requests_Functions.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" 
                                                          />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My problem now is, that I don't know how to get the SelectedItem (Requests_Functions.Name) properly in the ViewModel, because it is a related table and not directly coming from the ListCollectionView-Entity.
Does someone know a way how to get the SelectedItem? I tried with RowEditEnding EventTrigger but always stucking with the problem that the SelectedItem is not the same Entity as the ListCollectionView-Entity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with an `IValueConverter` that converts between the type of objects in the combobox list and the corresponding property of the objects in the data grid - add it to the `SelectedItem` binding of ComboBox?

The binding should then only be:

```
<... SelectedItem="{Binding Name, Mode... etc., Converter={StaticResource myConverter}" >
```

---

The following simple example shows how it works:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }

  public class AllNamesProvider 
  {
    public AllNamesProvider()
    {
      AllNames = new ObservableCollection<Name>
      {
        new Name { FirstName = "aaaa", LastName = "AAAA" },
        new Name { FirstName = "bbbb", LastName = "BBBB" },
        new Name { FirstName = "cccc", LastName = "CCCC" },
        new Name { FirstName = "dddd", LastName = "DDDD" },
        new Name { FirstName = "eeee", LastName = "EEEE" },
        new Name { FirstName = "ffff", LastName = "FFFF" },
      };
    }


    public ObservableCollection<Name> AllNames
    {
      get;
    }
  }

  public class Name : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private string m_firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
      get { return m_firstName; }
      set
      {
        m_firstName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
      }
    }

    private string m_lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
      get { return m_lastName; }
      set
      {
        m_lastName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
      }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string v)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }

  public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private int m_id;
    public int Id
    {
      get { return m_id; }
      set
      {
        m_id = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Id");
      }
    }

    private string m_name;
    public string Name
    {
      get { return m_name; }
      set
      {
        m_name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
      }
    }


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string v)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }


  public class ViewModel
  {
    public ViewModel()
    {
      Persons = new ListCollectionView(new List<Person>
      {
        new Person { Id = 1, Name = "AAAA"},
        new Person { Id = 2, Name = "BBBB"},
        new Person { Id = 3, Name = "CCCC"},
      });
    }


    public ListCollectionView Persons { get; set; }

    void RaisePropertyChanged()
    {

    }
  }
```

With a `NameConverter`:

```
  public class NameConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return (value as Name).LastName;
    }
  }
```

---

And here is the XAML:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:AllNamesProvider x:Key="NamesProvider" />
    <local:NameConverter x:Key="NameConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" >
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name1" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="200" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name2" Width="200">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllNames, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=NamesProvider}}"                        
                        DisplayMemberPath="LastName"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <ComboBox 
      ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NamesProvider}"
      DisplayMemberPath="LastName"
      Grid.Row="1" />
  </Grid>
```

Just create a default WPF project in Visual Studio and paste the above in to `MainWindow` files.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your fast answer! Unfortunately I have just little knowledge of Converters yet. Can you maybe shortly show how to implement the Convert method? Because I don't know how it helps me then to get the value in the ViewModel.